# Swift map annotations

Tags: ios, swift, mapkit

I am trying to get an annotation on the user location but I can't get a (sort of) speech bubble for my annotation's details. Is there any option to create something like this?

```
//AnnotationSettings
let newPin = MKPointAnnotation()
//set region on the map
maphome.setRegion(region, animated: true)
newPin.coordinate = location.coordinate
newPin.title = "aksldfjaskldfjaklsdfa"
newPin.subtitle = "sounds awesome!"
maphome.addAnnotation(newPin)
```

This is my code for the annotation.

[image: example]

Comment: annotation with a custom `UIView`

Answer (score 2):

You should set `canShowCallout = true`.

```
func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, viewFor annotation: MKAnnotation) -> MKAnnotationView? {
    if annotation is MKUserLocation {
        return nil
    }

    let reuseId = "pin"
    var pinView = mapView.dequeueReusableAnnotationView(withIdentifier: reuseId) as? MKMarkerAnnotationView
    if pinView == nil {
        pinView = MKMarkerAnnotationView(annotation: annotation, reuseIdentifier: reuseId)
        pinView?.canShowCallout = true

        let rightButton: AnyObject! = UIButton(type: UIButtonType.detailDisclosure)
        pinView?.rightCalloutAccessoryView = rightButton as? UIView
    }
    else {
        pinView?.annotation = annotation
    }

    return pinView
}
```

Comment: Did you set mapView's delegate to your view controller?

Answer (score 0):

yes, you can try this

```
    func mapView(_ mapView: MGLMapView, annotationCanShowCallout annotation: MGLAnnotation) -> Bool {
    // Always allow callouts to popup when annotations are tapped.
    return true
}
```